# import.meta.webpackContext returns undefined but still manages to get into an if block

Tags: angular, webpack

Node Version: 18.12.1
Angular Version: 15.0.4

I'm using import.meta.webpackContext but I get this console error: `{}.webpackContext is not a function`

I wrapped this function call in an if statement to avoid the error but it's still entering. Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

```
console.log("AAA: import meta webpackContext: ", import.meta.webpackContext);
if (import.meta.webpackContext) {
  console.log("AAA: but entered here");
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./services/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./components/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./directives/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./filters/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./native-extensions/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./prototypes/', ESM_CONFIG));
  importAll(import.meta.webpackContext('./views/', ESM_CONFIG));
} else {
  console.log("AAA: should enter here");
}
```

From the screenshot you can see it's logging undefined but ends up in the if block and not the else block.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from require.context to import.meta.webpackContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028454/migrating-from-require-context-to-import-meta-webpackcontext)

Answer (score 0):

`if(a) then a().` But `a = true` then you can't do `true()` => You can log it out to see if it's actually a function.

One of the ways to check if a variable is a function is using `typeof` which will return a string `'function'`.
`typeof(a) === 'function' ? a() : 'not a func'`